# Can I attach and then retrieve my own class descending from android.os.ResultReceiver to an Intent?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-intent, casting

I'm trying to make a class that extends Android's `ResultReceiver` for use with a custom `IntentService`. The problem is that when I try to attach my receiver to an `Intent` using `putExtra` and then retrieve it in `onHandleIntent` that I am unable to cast it to the child class. A simple code example can be seen here.

```
public class MyReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public JSONReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }
}

public class MyService extends IntentService {
    private static final String EXTRA_RECEIVER = "com.myname.extra.receiver";

    protected static void sendIntent(Context context, MyReceiver receiver) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER, receiver);
        //outputs com.myname.MyReceiver
        Log.i("type", receiver.getClass().getName());
        //outputs com.myname.MyReceiver
        Log.i("type", intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER).getClass().getName());
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final Parcelable parcelable = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER);
            //outputs android.os.ResultReceiver
            Log.i("type", parcelable.getClass().getName());
            //results in a casting error
            final MyReceiver receiver = (MyReceiver) parcelable;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the retrieval works as expected before calling `startService` so something must be happening between that and `onHandleIntent` being called that changes what the receiver is an instance of. I'm curious why/how this is happening and also if it is possible to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish here. Thanks!